# django throttle rate limit for specific unauthenticated user based ip address

Tags: python, django

i have setup as given instructions https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/
and my setup code is
setting.py

"""

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '5/min',
        'anon_day': '10/day',
        'user': '10/min',
        'user_day': '20/day',
    }
```

"""

and custom throttle.py

"""

```
from rest_framework.throttling import AnonRateThrottle, UserRateThrottle


class AnonDayThrottle(AnonRateThrottle):
    scope = 'anon_day'


class UserDayThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'user_day'
```

"""
and assign to api class comparable_summary.py
"""

```
from rest_framework.throttling import AnonRateThrottle
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .throttle import AnonDayThrottle


LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ComparablesSummaryAPI(APIView):
"""

apis performs for given response
"""
throttle_classes = [AnonDayThrottle, AnonRateThrottle]
```

"""

my question is i have checked two different ip_addresses but it consider unique ip_address for all request, please help me
thank for your help

Comment: What [cache](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#setting-up-the-cache) are you using? Are you testing this out locally or have you deployed your application somewhere? Some deployment services don't keep your application running and only start it up when receiving a request that is that the case for you?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any proxy in front of the application instance? If yes, you might want to setup `NUM_PROXIES` setting of django rest framework.

> If you need to strictly identify unique client IP addresses, you'll need to first configure the number of application proxies that the API runs behind by setting the NUM_PROXIES setting. This setting should be an integer of zero or more. If set to non-zero then the client IP will be identified as being the last IP address in the X-Forwarded-For header, once any application proxy IP addresses have first been excluded. If set to zero, then the REMOTE_ADDR value will always be used as the identifying IP address.

- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#how-clients-are-identified
- https://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=AppSuite:Grizzly#Multiple_Proxies_in_front_of_the_cluster